# What is a faster way to sort these string inputs based on their position in the sentence?

Tags: c++, optimization

Practicing for the national Olympiad of Informatics  stumbled a problem that goes as follows:
The user inputs the amount of words (n) in the sentence and the proceeds on entering the words along with their positions separated by a space.
You are asked to input the sentence with the correct order of words.

For example:

Input:

```
4
this 1
sentence 4
is 2
a 3
```

Output:

```
this is a sentence
```

Restrictions:

```
1 <= N <= 3 * 10^5
1 <= Size of a word <= 50
```

I have tried to solve this problem using an unordered_map and it turns out is solves this pretty fast taking only 0.588 seconds going over all the test cases which made my solution the 5th fastest out of 45. However the fastest solution only takes 0.14 seconds to compute and I can't figure out how he/she did it. What is a faster way to solve this problem than using unordered_map?

```
unordered_map < int, string > words;    
int n;    
cin >> n;  
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {    
    string word;    
    int position;     
    cin >> word >> position;    
    words[position] = word;    
}    
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {     
    cout << words[i] << "\n";      
}
```

Comment: Are you also measuring the output in your timing?

Comment: why not simply use a vector? The index after the word minus 1 is the index in the vector. The size of the vector you know from the first input. ``std::vector<std::string> v ... v.[index-1] = s;``

Answer (score 5):

`std::unordered_map` is a little overboard for this problem.  Since you are provided the order that the elements will be in you can get away with a `std::vector<std::string>`, and you just put the elements in the vector where the input tells you.  That simplifies the program code to

```
int main()
{
    int records;
    std::cin >> records;
    std::vector<std::string> sentence(records);
    std::string word;
    int place;
    while (std::cin >> word >> place)
        sentence[place - 1] = std::move(word); // subtract one as input is 1 based index, use move to save an allocation and copy
    for (auto const& e : sentence)
        std::cout << e << " ";
}
```

Comment: And even `sentence[place - 1] = std::move(word);`

Comment: It lowers the time down to 0.528 but still not the 0.12 that has the first spot. Any ideas as to how they made it complete that fast?

Comment: @Reakles cout and cin are slow.

Comment: @ZDF Was the .12 solution using C++?  If they fell back to C and used `printf` and c-strings it would probably be faster as the streams are slowww.

Comment: Maybe they are minimizing memory allocations.

Comment: @ZDF no one gets arrested if they use ``printf`` in a c++ program. Actually - being an old fart of programming I only use ``iostream`` when it really does not matter, ``cstdio`` is my default.